# Swift: class methods may only be declared on a type

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-warnings

I am getting the compiler error "Class methods may only be declared on a type". I am not sure why I am getting this to be honest. All the stack overflow answers apply to another senario. Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
       class func fontWithSize(var size : CGFloat) -> UIFont
       {
       let font : UIFont = UIFont (name: "Roboto-Regular", size: size)!
       return font;
       }
```

Comment: Try removing the `var` keyword in your method parameter.

Comment: Is this `class func fontWithSize` contained within a `class Foo { ... }`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing that looks odd is the `var` keyword in front of the parameter name.
The other thing; are you declaring this method inside a `class` definition?
You're probably getting this error because you're declaring the method at the top-level or global scope. If that's your intention the you don't need the `class` keyword anyway.

Comment: This is correct, thank you. I will give your answer the approval once the time limit is up.